# MVC Api Controller confusion with JSON.stringify

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I know how to post to Umbraco's Api Controller, that's not the issue.

**Question:**

Let us say that we have (2) Api methods:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Test1(string time, string activityType)
    {
        return time;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Test2(SomeModel model)
    {
        return model.SomeProperty;
    }
```

On the first method/ajax call, if I stringify the "time" and "activityType", I get this error:

```
url: '/Umbraco/api/SomeApi/Test1',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify({time: '10', activityType: 'test'}),
```

*UmbracoApiController - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI*

---

Instead, I have to append the (2) parameters as a querystring, and it works. However, in the 2nd Api method, I have a model, and I can use the stringify method for JSON, and it works.

**Why? Is this the same with regular MVC as well??**

---

We have (2) ajax calls, and these both work:

```
// you can see that I have to append via querystring in this instance
$.ajax({
        url: '/Umbraco/api/SomeApi/Test1?time=' + time + '&activityType=' + activityType,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        // doesn't work ****
        // url: '/Umbraco/api/SomeApi/Test1',
        // data: JSON.stringify({time: '10', activityType: 'test'}),
        // **********************
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        complete: function (data) {
            var test= $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            console.log(test);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });

var post = {
   SomeProperty : 'test',
   AnotherProperty: 'blahblah'
};

$.ajax({
        url: '/Umbraco/api/SomeApi/Test2',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(post),
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        complete: function (data) {
            var test= $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            console.log(test);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebAPI's model binder looks in the query string by default when binding "simple" types like strings. This is different from MVC. Use the `[FromBody]` attribute to tell it that it should look in the request body instead.

```
public string Test1([FromBody]string time, [FromBody]string activityType)
```

Edit: It turns out that WebAPI reads the body as a stream instead of caching it like in MVC. That means `[FromBody]` can only be applied to one parameter. You will need to either pass one in the URI and one in the body or create a complex type that contains both of your parameters.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to post.

Comment: Apprec - didn't know if this was different when using Umbraco since they auto-route.

Comment: Quick ? - what if I pass (2) models? Would the above answer be applied? `......[FromBody]SomeModel model1, [FromBody]AbcModel model2)`. These params aren't "simple" types as you put it.

Comment: See my edit. My original answer won't work. It also means your follow up question isn't possible. You would have to combine your two models into a single model.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is by design and well [documented](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> - **If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI**. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a string. (More about type converters later.)
> - **For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body**, using a media-type formatter.

To force Web API to look in the body for simple types, you can decorate the parameters with the [[FromBody]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute e.g.

```
public string Test1([FromBody]string time, [FromBody]string activityType)
```